# Bad CPU type in executable while typing tar command

Tags: ruby, macos, tar, osx-mountain-lion

recently i have upgraded to mountain lion and there is problem with my tar command, i am not able to unpack my tar files from terminal.
when i type tar command in terminal i am geting

bash: /usr/bin/tar: Bad CPU type in executable

can anyone tell me a solution ,
so that i can fix the problem

thanks
gsk

Comment: Why is this tagged "ruby"? Did you try to Google that error message?

Comment: What is the output of `md5sum /usr/bin/tar `?